# Provide HTML-attribute LANG in multilanguage sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint

I have to create a master page for Sharepoint and include the correct HTML-attribute lang (html lang="en" e.g.).
What is the best way to do this? Is there a resource like <%$Resources:wss, multipages_direction_dir_value %> used for html:dir?
I don't want to create custom code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use language resources for that. If I'm not mistaken, this is how the default SharePoint master pages are written

Comment: I have taken a look at Sharepoint masterpages, but lang-attribute is not provided. Only the attribute html:dir, but not for language. 
So, i am looking for the resourcekey to provide languagekey... I could not find it yet :(

Comment: You can always create your own RESX files and add the translation for this property. You just create a resource file in Visual Studio, name it [yourname][your language].resx and put it under the App_GlobalResources, then you can reference it in the master page

Answer (score 0):

In 2010 you have <%$Resources:wss,language_value%>

But there isn't any similar resource in the previous versions

Comment: We use 2007... :( Thanks for this information, I will add a resourcekey myself.